# HTML, CSS and Javascript very cool border rotating glowing effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i came accross the following template but due to the fact they have base64 encrypted their javascript / page elements for god only knows what reason it makes seeing the source code very difficult.

http://yootheme.com/demo/themes/joomla/2010/planet/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=44&Itemid=53&preset=default

But on that page the header bar with the class "header-bg" seems to have the background-position constantly changing most likely via the use of javascript and i like the design and effect of the colors so i am curious if someone can help me or fiddle to me a demo of how they are doing this.

I love the way the border effect is constantly rotating around in different variations of colors like that. (Not sure if anyone else finds that beautiful)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to make the rotating/glowing effect around the border like they have done on that site. Since it is always changing color.

Comment: It's an image containing a color gradient and they're just animating the background position via JavaScript.

Comment: So there is no way to do this without images ? Anyone could do this with a animated gif i think :P

Comment: They did it with png images in the front and a jpg in the background. I think an animated gif will not be able to do that, unless you want to generate a 10 MB gif file with hundreds of frames. You cannot get that quality of animation with an animated gif.

Comment: They must be using some form of javascript to change the colors constantly like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use a background image, and they animate `background-position` using JS.

Here I use CSS animations instead:

```css
@keyframes bg {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 1500px 0;
  }
}
.header-bg {
  border-radius: 15px; /* outerRadius */ 
  padding: 3px;        /* separation */ 
  animation: bg 10s infinite linear;
  background: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,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") repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
}
.header-inner {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;  /* outerRadius - separation */
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-bg">
  <div class="header-inner">Foo bar</div>
</div>
```

Also note that a gradient could be used instead of that image.

Comment: Thanks thats it :D would it be better with gradient since it saves loading images.

Comment: @Oriol the animation doesn't seem to work in my chrome, but it works in firefox. not sure why.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Chrome still needs `-webkit-` vendor prefixes. Both in `-webkit-animation` and `@-webkit-keyframes`. See [an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Cylon_Eye) of an implementation for major browsers.

Comment: that's not it. definitely not for the `animation` property, anyway.